# How to query for menu items that can be shown/hidden with Content Permissions in Orchard Core?

Tags: graphql, orchardcms

I have 3 roles (all, only1, only2), 3 respected users (seeall,only1 ,only2),  3 menu items (a, b, c).
`Under Edit Link Menu Item` section I assigned roles to menu items.

My aim is to show menu items for those users.

I authenticate users with connect/token , using `grant_type:'password'`

when I query graphql, I got all the menu items. Not respecting roles.

How can I modify query to get only permitted menu items?

[image]